# How to get LinkedTxn for paid invoice

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to get invoice detail from Quickbook desktop (QB enterprise 16-Us)) but unable to get LinkedTxn detail under paid invoice in Quickbook invoice response.I have implemented WCF service and process via web connector.

This is the qbxml request :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?qbxml version="13.0"?> 
<QBXML> 
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError"> 
<InvoiceQueryRq iterator="Start" requestID=""> 
<MaxReturned>15</MaxReturned> 
<ModifiedDateRangeFilter> 
<FromModifiedDate>2017-11-21</FromModifiedDate> 
<ToModifiedDate>2017-11-29</ToModifiedDate> 
</ModifiedDateRangeFilter> 
<IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems> 
</InvoiceQueryRq> 
</QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

This is Quickbook response :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<InvoiceQueryRs requestID="" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK" iteratorRemainingCount="0" iteratorID="{7c171bcc-41fb-4f68-81a0-e6b953f83031}">
<InvoiceRet>
<TxnID>CE48-1511360942</TxnID>
<TimeCreated>2017-11-22T19:59:02+05:30</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2017-11-23T15:08:20+05:30</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>1511360942</EditSequence>
<TxnNumber>8931</TxnNumber>
<CustomerRef>
<ListID>8000059D-1511360941</ListID>
<FullName>abc test</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef>
<ListID>290000-1123910337</ListID>
<FullName>Ac Receivables</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<TemplateRef>
<ListID>60000-1127707865</ListID>
<FullName>IAQ Invoice</FullName>
</TemplateRef>
<TxnDate>2017-11-21</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>3437</RefNumber>
<BillAddress>
<Addr1>xyz</Addr1>
<City>txy</City>
<PostalCode>123</PostalCode>
</BillAddress>
<BillAddressBlock>
<Addr1>xyz Road</Addr1>
<Addr2>test 123</Addr2>
</BillAddressBlock>
<ShipAddress>
<Addr1>xyz</Addr1>
<City>abc</City>
<PostalCode>123</PostalCode>
</ShipAddress>
<ShipAddressBlock>
<Addr1>83 anc</Addr1>
<Addr3>abc</Addr3>
</ShipAddressBlock>
<IsPending>false</IsPending>
<IsFinanceCharge>false</IsFinanceCharge>
<TermsRef>
<ListID>80000-1154076245</ListID>
<FullName>C.O.D</FullName>
</TermsRef>
<DueDate>2017-11-21</DueDate>
<SalesRepRef>
<ListID>80000009-1355185246</ListID>
<FullName>KAS</FullName>
</SalesRepRef>
<ShipDate>2017-11-22</ShipDate>
<Subtotal>1450.00</Subtotal>
<SalesTaxPercentage>0.00</SalesTaxPercentage>
<SalesTaxTotal>0.00</SalesTaxTotal>
<AppliedAmount>-1450.00</AppliedAmount>
<BalanceRemaining>0.00</BalanceRemaining>
<IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
<IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
<IsToBeEmailed>false</IsToBeEmailed>
<InvoiceLineRet>
<TxnLineID>CE4A-1511360942</TxnLineID>
<ItemRef>
<ListID>10000-1123911430</ListID>
<FullName>IAQ Testing</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>1) test per point</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Rate>900.00</Rate>
<Amount>900.00</Amount>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>20000-1123906706</ListID>
<FullName>Non</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
</InvoiceLineRet>
<InvoiceLineRet>
<TxnLineID>CE4B-1511360942</TxnLineID>
<ItemRef>
<ListID>20000-1123911718</ListID>
<FullName>Other Services</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>2) test point</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Rate>400.00</Rate>
<Amount>400.00</Amount>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>20000-1123906706</ListID>
<FullName>Non</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
</InvoiceLineRet>
<InvoiceLineRet>
<TxnLineID>CE4C-1511360942</TxnLineID>
<ItemRef>
<ListID>10000-1123911430</ListID>
<FullName>IAQ Testing</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>3) test Reporting</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Rate>150.00</Rate>
<Amount>150.00</Amount>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>20000-1123906706</ListID>
<FullName>Non</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
</InvoiceLineRet>
</InvoiceRet>
</InvoiceQueryRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `IncludeLinkedTxns` section on your request, same as the IncludeLineItems one